# Issue with Json Response in C# when RESPONSE write two fields in foreign language

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jsonserializer

i make web service in c# which write with HTTP RESPONE.WRITE
json answer but the problem is when i return the json with some field which included the hebrew langauge , after that the json response is not full the end bracket miss.. i put the code in c# and the response of the json string

json response with hebrew fields

```
{"Response":"OK","FName":"איגור","LName":"kurylo","User_Name":"0524858214","ErrorMsg":"P
```

json response regulat with english fields :

```
{"Response":"OK","FName":"igor","LName":"kurylo","User_Name":"0524858218","ErrorMsg":"Pass"}
```

and thie my code in web service
this the model of the json response

```
public class Android_Reg
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string User_Name { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }   
}

string l = Convert.ToString(jSon.Serialize(reg).ToString().Length);
string jsonr = jSon.Serialize(reg).ToString();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reg, Formatting.Indented);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", l);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(jsonr);
```

thank you for help :)

**EDIT:**
ok i do some test i debuig the my web service and i find out the next details 
after

```
 string jsonr = jSon.Serialize(reg).ToString();
```

this command the jsonr get the next string also with hebrew and english fields 
jsonr

```
"{\"Response\":\"OK\",\"FName\":\"igor\",\"LName\":\"kurylo\",\"User_Name\":\"0524858281\",\"ErrorMsg\":\"Pass\"}"


"{\"Response\":\"OK\",\"FName\":\"איגור\",\"LName\":\"קורילו\",\"User_Name\":\"0524858270\",\"ErrorMsg\":\"Pass\"}"
```

maybe becaouse the \ the string is truncated and i check out the lenght of both ofthe string the the first string is 92 charachters and the second is 92

Comment: `"ErrorMsg":"P` are you sure it is dropping the curly braces and not truncating the string somehow?

Comment: look this also truncating the string but it's only happens when i back in hebrew langauge fields  look the other json string this is the full string

Comment: I'd be curious if the string length changes if it always truncates on P or at a character position (l.IndexOf(x))? 

Also, where is reg? Is there another class or is that Android_reg?

Comment: reg is a Android_reg and i check aboout the lenght of the string the string in still in with same length ..

Comment: Can you clarify on that length? So it truncates at a constant length when Hebrew characters are present?

Comment: yes it's truncate when the Hebrew chars are present i will check it now again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to test this but I think the problem lies with the length of the string in the line `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", l);`

The length of your Hebrew string is five and the number of missing characters is 5. To encode the Hebrew it will be using a double-byte encoding, hence the 5 missing characters. If you add to `l` the number of Hebrew characters I believe the problem will go away. To test it just use `l + 5`.

Comment: ok dude you are right i add to the l the lenght of the First name and last Name and this work :) thank you

Comment: @IgorKurylo, no problem; if you liked the answer, could you please accept it. Thanks

Comment: Had been my thought as well! Nice.